# Workaround for @Formular bug

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a little problem to find an appropiate workaround for [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7525) bug.

I need both the birthdate of a user and the next birthday as a persisted field in the entity class. The mentioned workaround uses `@ColumnTransfer` which needs a `@Column` Annotation, too. But there is no column "nextBirthday" or something like that and refering to `birthdate` won't work (column ambiguously defined).

My original `User` class is:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ID
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthdate;

    @Formula("add_months(birthDate, floor(months_between(sysdate - 1, birthDate) /12 + 1) * 12)")
    private Date nextBirthday;

    // More Fields
}
```

My first attempt to use `@ColumnTransformer`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ID
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column("birthdate")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "add_months(birthDate, floor(months_between(sysdate - 1, birthDate) /12 + 1) * 12)")
    private Date nextBirthday;

    // More Fields
}
```

This does not work, because there are two field refering to birthdate.

Does anyone know a workaround without refering to a column?

Comment: just create a getter method for nextBirthday field. Fetch and initialize your field here. You don't need ColumnTransformer or something like that.

Comment: you could do the nextBirthday calculation in the getter rather than  doing it in sql or using @ColumnTrasnfer

Comment: I have to use nextBirthday with the Criteria API. It needs to be accessable with ``javax.persistence.criteria.Path.get(String attributeName)``. Therefore ``@Transient`` does not help me here.